# JDBC, spring: How to bulk update using JdbcTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to update one Column data with the value. CARD Table Example likes below.

| id | column_for_update |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 13 |
| 5 | 14 |
...

Using jdbcTemplate(or other possible templates), I wanted to update column_for_update to 1000 * n(n = 1, 2, 3 ..), and result will be like ['10, 11, 12 ...'] -> ['1000, 2000, 3000'].

It is possible importing all objects into the application level and update them, but importing a large number of objects causes outOfMemory exceptions. How can I update this columns efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing your query to use a `UPDATE`/`SELECT` to multiply your `id` column by `1000`:

```
UPDATE card a
INNER JOIN card b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.column_for_update = (b.id * 1000)
```

| **id** | **column for update** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 3000 |
| 4 | 4000 |
| 5 | 5000 |

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ROwDzECV).

Comment: Sorry,I corrected my question. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer. I’m not sure if this is compatible with jdbc template though. Let me know and I’ll remove my answer.

Comment: I wanted to increase this value with a Multiplication of a particular value(1000 * n, n = 1, 2, 3 ...), but I think it's a good idea to multiply the existing value by 1000. It's working well. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. The id column normally wouldn’t be used for a calculation like this, assuming that it’s a primary key, it’s  more of an identifier. But for your scenario that you provided, as long your id column is consistent, it should work.